# Why does docker -itd make a container run while docker -d makes it exit

Tags: docker

I would like to know why `docker -i -t -d centos /bin/bash` makes a container run in background while `docker -d centos /bin/bash` make a container go to exit state

Hey guys, I am trying to understand why `-i -t` makes a container stay in active state. I would have thought that `-d` would have been enough in above scenario.

```
$ docker run -d --name mycentos3 centos
0bebdb11f3796bf5ac1ee9b0f132c3b3a4fcc2390f77aa971e6700d025025ebb

docker run -i -t -d --name mycentos4 centos
2be599d7310677c53c6f1dd1b5c70106f4c33f3193aad466ca34f0855173e559

docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

2be599d73106        centos              "/bin/bash"         Less than a second ago   Up 1 second                             mycentos4
```

Comment: What you are doing is basically exactly equivalent to typing `bash &` at a command prompt.  What do you expect to happen in this simpler non-Docker case, and why?

Comment: @DavidMaze -- the bash & now makes it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash is an interactive prompt. It consumes input from STDIN.

`-i` is necessary in order for Docker to keep a STDIN open. Without it: bash would reach the end of input and terminate.

`-d` is not related to your problem.
`-t` is not responsible for bash's exiting, but it's good to use `-t` for interactive prompts like bash, so that Docker provides a pseudo-TTY into which bash can write prompts (e.g. your PS1) and control sequences (e.g. colour).

Comment: Yep thanks !.. I see.. and do you know the different between `docker run -i` and `docker run -a STDIN`

Comment: Looks like `-i` is exactly the same as `-a STDIN`. though `-i` is evaluated later (i.e. with higher precedence), and specifying _any_ `-a` option undoes the default config (which is to "attach to STDOUT + STDERR")

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/4118e0c9eebda2412a09ae66e90c34b85fae3275/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L252-L271